# VueJS component throws warning if data has property that parent does not

Tags: components, vuejs2

I have a simple component handled by `<script type="text/x-template"...`, and it has its own data object that has only one property to control whether or not to show a div.

I am getting the following warning in Console:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "showDiv" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. (found in root instance)

Live demo: https://jsbin.com/zucaqog/edit?html,js,output

**Js:**

```
Vue.component('my-comp', {
    template: '#my-comp',
    data: function() {
      return { showDiv: false };
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {}
});
```

If I add `showDiv: false` to the parent's `data` object, I no longer receive the warning. But, I'd like to avoid doing that since this data property is relevant only to the local scope of the component. I have a feeling if I put the html of the component as a string in the `template: ...` then it might work, but, I'd rather have it inside of a `script`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have your child component's template definition as a child of the `#app` div. The parent component is seeing that there is a reference to the `showDiv` variable inside of its template, so it's throwing the error.

Pull that `x-template` outside of the `#app` div:

```
<div id="app">
  <my-comp></my-comp>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="my-comp">
  <div>
    Value of showDiv is {{showDiv}}. 
    <button @click="showDiv=!showDiv">Toggle showDiv</button>
  </div>
</script>
```